# trouble with the logger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i had an error when trying some logs:

```
NoMethodError in RelationController#create  
undefined method `attributes' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x431e650>
```

this is my controller

```
def create
    follow = User.find(params[:relation][:following_id])
    current_user.following << follow
    logger.debug "follow: #{follow.attributes.inspect}"
    logger.debug "current_user: #{current_user.attributes.values}" 
    logger.debug "following: #{current_user.following.attributes.values}"
    redirect_to follow
  end
```

what can i do to fix that, please help me!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of your error is this line

```
logger.debug "following: #{current_user.following.attributes.values}"
```

You're calling `attributes` on `current_user.following` which is an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object.  If you want to log, you have to loop through each of `current_user.following` and call `attributes` on it

```
current_user.following.each do |follow|
  logger.debug "following: #{follow.attributes.values}"
end
```